# Is therre another way for adding a ID on URL http Delete request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever i send a request to the server(to delete an item with a specific id) i have the following error:
Cannot DELETE /url/url/:id/:16857.
I know it is supposed to look like /url/url/16857 but i dont know where the problem is... i deleted the '/:' part from the response but still I got fast the same error only without the '/:'

I have created an Http Delete request like follow:

```
function(parameter: Parameter) {
    return new Promise<boolean>( (resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.delete<boolean>(URL+'/:'+parameter.id, Options).subscribe( 
        (res => { resolve(res); }));
    });
  }
```

and on the server side I have the response like:

```
router.delete('/url/url:id', function (req,res)
{
        //some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In http request you don't need add the ':', you just need put like below:

```
this.http.delete<boolean>(`${URL}/${parameter.id}`, Options)
    .subscribe(res => { 
        resolve(res); 
     });
```

I do recommend you to use template strings ``, it's better for reference a variable.

In you server side, it's recomended:

```
router.delete('/url/v1/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    // It's referenced automatically to variable if exist in req.body
    const { id } = req.body;
});
```

I hope it can help you.